# f.getContentPane().add(new hellojava2(" hello, java"));

Tags: java, swing

```
f.getContentPane().add(new hellojava2(" hello, java"));
```

i have this code in my program but it doesn' t have any effect. that means "hello,java" should appear in f frame but it does not. hellojava2 is the program itself. i do not get error message too.

Comment: You need to give more context and if possible provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: what _is_ `hellojava2`? Is it a custom component?

Comment: You really need to provide the source for `hellojava2` if you want anybody to be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

> *"hello,java" should appear in f frame but it does not. hellojava2 is the program itself.  i do not get error message too."*

If you are not getting any errors, I'm going to assume your program extends `JFrame`, since the `JFrame` needs a component to be added and I doubt your program `extends JLabel` and `JPanel` has no constructor with a `String` parameter

- If this is the case, you should realize that the constructor `JFrame(String s)` only sets the title for the frame. Nothing is *printed* .
- Also if this is the case, it looks like you're trying to add a JFrame to a JFrame, which won't work either.
- Also if this is the case, it seems like you trying to create another `JFrame f` when your class is already a `JFrame`. No need for that.

---

Try something like this as a simple `HelloWorld` Program. All I do is add a `JLabel` to a `JFrame`

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
                frame.add(new JLabel("Hello, World"));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Also take some time to go over the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)